# Setting transformation of bone instead of transforming it through python

Tags: python, animation

I have a bone, and I want it to be rotated to a specific value I have calculated in a matrix. I know I can use editBone.transform() but this adds to the existing transformation and that's not my goal, I want it to end up to the transformation I have in the matrix, not combine them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

obj = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]
bone = obj.data.bones["Bone"]
loc, rot, sca = your_matrix.decompose() # your 4x4 matrix
print(loc)
print(rot)
print(sca)

# bone.matrix is read-only, so you need change the head and tail
print("head:", bone.head)
print("tail:", bone.tail)

# set head location
l = bone.length
bone.head = loc
direction = rot @ Vector((0, 1, 0))
# set tail location, when scale is 1, 1, 1
bone.tail = bone.head + direction * l


# direction[0] *= sca[0]
# direction[1] *= sca[1]
# direction[2] *= sca[2]
# bone.tail = bone.head + direction * l
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was experimenting with something similar, though I think Z is up in Blender, Im gonna see if I can implement this! Wow!!!!!